# RecyclerView.OnBindViewHolder click gets invoked multiple time?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I have a `Grid RecyclerView` (3 column) and I added a delegate click listener inside `OnBindViewHolder` method.

**Scenario (Log attached)**

Let say I have 18 items, which is 6 rows. By default without any scrolling, I can only see 2.5 rows.

When I click the item (position 0-8), the delegate function get invoked only once (Attempt 1 ~ 2).

When I scroll to the end of the page, and I click one of the item, the delegate function get invoked once (Attempt 3).

And if I scroll back up, and click one of the item the delegate function get invoked 4 times (Attempt 4).

In my (Attempt 5), I scroll it to the bottom and clicked an item, this time, the delegate function get invoked twice.

Note:

- I am using `Xamarin.Android`
- I only clicked those item once
- I have tested with multiple device and getting the same result
- The number of delegate function invoked is not fixed, sometimes might invoked up to 6 times per click.

> My question is why is this happen and is there any other proper way to implement this?

**Log**

```
// Attempt 1 : (I clicked position 1)
[[Log ==== ]] [Time : 9/12/2015 10:36:44 AM ] Clicked position [1]
// Attempt 2 : (I clicked position 3)
[[Log ==== ]] [Time : 9/12/2015 10:36:52 AM ] Clicked position [3]
// Attempt 3 : (I scroll it till the end of the page and clicked position 14)
[[Log ==== ]] [Time : 9/12/2015 10:36:52 AM ] Clicked position [14]
// Attempt 4 : (I scroll it back to the top and clicked position 1)
[[Log ==== ]] [Time : 9/12/2015 10:40:08 AM ] Clicked position [4]
[[Log ==== ]] [Time : 9/12/2015 10:40:08 AM ] Clicked position [15]
[[Log ==== ]] [Time : 9/12/2015 10:40:08 AM ] Clicked position [5]
[[Log ==== ]] [Time : 9/12/2015 10:40:08 AM ] Clicked position [16]
[[Log ==== ]] [Time : 9/12/2015 10:40:08 AM ] Clicked position [1]
// Attempt 5 : (I scroll it down again and clicked position 14)
[[Log ==== ]] [Time : 9/12/2015 10:41:57 AM ] Clicked position [11]
[[Log ==== ]] [Time : 9/12/2015 10:41:57 AM ] Clicked position [14]
```

**Activity**

```
[Activity (Label = "DrinksMenuCategory", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.ActionBar")]          
public class DrinksMenuCategory : AppCompatActivity
{
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    private int selected_drinksCategory;
    private List<Drinks> drinksCategory;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Activity_DrinksMenuCategoryGridview);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);

        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView> (Resource.Id.recyclerView_drinksMenuCategoryGridView);
        mRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager (this, 3);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager (mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new DrinksMenuCategoryRecyclerAdapter (drinksCategory, mRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter (mAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Adapter & ViewHolder**

```
public class DrinksMenuCategoryRecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public List<Drinks> mDrinksItems;
    public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public DrinksMenuCategoryRecyclerAdapter (List<Drinks> drinksItems, RecyclerView mRecyclerView)
    {
        this.mDrinksItems = drinksItems;
        this.mRecyclerView = mRecyclerView;
    }

    public override int GetItemViewType (int position)
    {
        return Resource.Layout.recyclerView_cell_drinksMenu_category;
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View row = LayoutInflater
            .From (parent.Context)
            .Inflate (Resource.Layout.recyclerView_cell_drinksMenu_category, parent, false);

        CardView v_drinksCard = row.FindViewById<CardView> (Resource.Id.drinks_card);
        ImageView v_drinksImage = row.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.drinks_image);
        TextView v_drinksText = row.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.drinks_text);

        DrinksMenuItemHolder viewHolder = new DrinksMenuItemHolder (row, parent.Context) {
            mDrinksCard = v_drinksCard,
            mDrinksImage = v_drinksImage,
            mDrinksText = v_drinksText
        };

        return viewHolder;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        DrinksMenuItemHolder viewHolder = holder as DrinksMenuItemHolder;
        viewHolder.mDrinksCard.Click += delegate {
            // *** Click Event ***
            Log.Debug ("[DrinksMenuCategoryRecyclerAdapter ==== ]", "[Time : " + DateTime.Now + " ] Clicked position [" + position + "]");
            Toast.MakeText (viewHolder.context, "[Time : " + DateTime.Now + " ] Clicked position [" + position + "]", ToastLength.Short).Show (); 
        };
        viewHolder.mDrinksText.Text = mDrinksItems[position].name;
    }

    public override int ItemCount {
        get { return mDrinksItems.Count; }
    }

    public class DrinksMenuItemHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public Context context { get; set; }
        public View mMainView { get; set; }

        public CardView mDrinksCard { get; set; }
        public ImageView mDrinksImage { get; set; }
        public TextView mDrinksText { get; set; }

        public DrinksMenuItemHolder (View view, Context context) : base (view)
        {
            this.context = context;
            mMainView = view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time bind is called, this also happens when the item is reused, then you add an eventhandler, meaning you will get multiple events if an item is reused and you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

(I know I'm late to the party, but whatever...)

```
viewHolder.mDrinksCard.Click += delegate {..}
```

Every time the `ViewhHolder` is bound (which happens a lot), you are creating a new delegate and adding it to a potentially existing view.  Over time, the views accumulate multiple `Click` delegates, each responding to a single click in turn.

You need to disconnect remove the `Click` delegate in `Adapter.onViewRecycled()`.